How to handle the same data in two different tabs
I have a TabLayout for two different type of Categories: Income & Expense. I get the all the categories using the CategoriesViewModel and observe the list for any changes. When a tab is selected I filter the categories so they're correctly displayed in that tab, remove any observers and add a new one. Problems are:

When changing tabs, sometimes, the categories from that selected tab will be displayed as if the previous categories were still there List of categories with empty space above them. So there will be an empty space above them as if the other categories are there when they are not.
When adding/deleting categories (on a specific tab), sometimes, the categories from the other tab will appear there and actually be created in the database with the current's tab type (for example, I have 3 income categories, when deleting from the expense's tab, (I don't know what triggers this error), sometimes, those 3 income categories will copy to the expense categories).

Fragment's onViewCreated():
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val categoriesRV = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.categories_recycler_view)
        currentTab = arguments?.getString("currentTab") ?: "income"
        val tabLayout = view.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.type_tab_layout)
        for (i in 0 until tabLayout.tabCount) {
            val tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i)
            val tabText = tab?.text?.toString()?.lowercase()
            if (tabText == currentTab) {
                tabLayout.selectTab(tab)
            }
        }

        categoryVM.getAllCategories().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { categories ->
            val filteredCategories = filterCategories(categories, currentTab)
            val categoriesAdapter = CategoriesAdapter(filteredCategories, this)
            categoriesRV.adapter = categoriesAdapter
        }

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                currentTab = tab?.text.toString().lowercase()

                if (categoryVM.getAllCategories().hasObservers()) categoryVM.getAllCategories().removeObservers(viewLifecycleOwner)

                categoryVM.getAllCategories().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { categories ->
                    val filteredCategories = filterCategories(categories, currentTab)
                    val categoriesAdapter =
                        CategoriesAdapter(filteredCategories, this@CategoriesFragment)
                    categoriesRV.adapter = categoriesAdapter
                }
            }

            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                // Handle tab reselect
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                // Handle tab unselect
            }
        })

        val newCategoryButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.new_category_button)
        newCategoryButton.setOnClickListener {
            openCategoryDialog(null) {
                categoryVM.addCategory(it.name, it.iconId, currentTab)
            }
        }
    }

CategoriesAdapter:
class CategoriesAdapter(
    private var categoryList: List<Category>,
    private val deleteClickListener: OnCategoryDeleteClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoriesAdapter.CategoriesViewHolder>() {

    class CategoriesViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val categoryName: TextView
        val categoryIcon: ImageView
        val deleteBadge: ImageButton

        init {
            categoryName = view.findViewById(R.id.category_name)
            categoryIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.category_icon)
            deleteBadge = view.findViewById(R.id.badgeIcon)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CategoriesViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_category, parent, false)
        return CategoriesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CategoriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val category = categoryList[position]
        holder.categoryName.text = category.name
        holder.categoryName
        if (category.iconId != null) {
            holder.categoryIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.categoryIcon.setImageResource(category.iconId)
            val layoutParams = holder.categoryIcon.layoutParams
            layoutParams.width = 130 // Adjust the width as per your requirement
            layoutParams.height = 130 // Adjust the height as per your requirement
            holder.categoryIcon.layoutParams = layoutParams
        }
        holder.deleteBadge.setOnClickListener {
            deleteClickListener.onDeleteClick(category)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = categoryList.size
}

interface OnCategoryDeleteClickListener {
    fun onDeleteClick(category: Category)
}


First of all, your view is doing the sorting. This should be done by the view model. So filter the transactions as expense list and income list from the view model, and observe both in their respective tabs. When you are adding a new item either expense or income, write to both the list and db(async, you would have to have some retry mechanism if necessary).
With two separate lists, there won't be duplicated data, solving problem no 1. With writing it both to db and the list, you don't have to depend on tab selection to determine what you are adding, instead each fragment will call their respective addExpense,addIncome methods.
